# Why does my aloe have so much space between its leaves?

Tags: succulents, aloe

I received this aloe About a year ago. I recently moved it from the nursery pot to a slightly larger pot. While looking up the best way to do that I noticed mine seems to have more space between leaves than most. What am I doing wrong? You’ll also notice a few damaged leaves thanks to my children. Should I do anything about those?

It’s in succulent soil. I water it once every 2-3weeks. It’s in a room with several large skylights so I believe it’s getting good indirect light.[image]

Answer (score 2):

It does look a bit etiolated - this is caused by insufficient light. If all the light in the room it lives is coming from above, fairly high up, its stretching itself out to try to reach more light.

If possible, find somewhere with a source of brighter daylight nearby,perhaps near an ordinary window.

Comment: That makes sense! The only natural light is from the skylights above. I’ll move it and see what happens.  
Thanks for the quick answer!